# Set a dataset with 1024 attributes in weka

Tags: image, dataset, weka

I am a beginner in weka and I have a training data set with lots of instances and each instance has 1024 binaries which shows  the pixels of a 32* 32 black and white image , each instance actually is an image representing a letter of alphabet A-Z which has index of 1 to 25 (25 classes)
How can I set this data set in weka?
I mean should I write 1024 attributes and 25 classes?how?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your instances consist of 1024 binary values, to be used to classify the data, and 25 different possible classifications*.

Assuming you saved your data in a logical way, i.e. using a comma to seperate all the different values, you could import your data into Excel. This should result in your data being split into 1025 different columns, 1024 columns containing your binary information and the final 1025th column containing the letter.

You would then be able to open the CSV file in the WEKA GUI client or convert the CSV file into an ARFF file for further use, whichever you prefer.

The above mentioned steps are illustrated below in images using some raw data I've gathered a few days ago (Raw data (.txt) -> Data processing (CSV) -> Input into WEKA (ARFF)):

[image: Raw data (TXT)]

[image: Processing the data (.csv)]

[image: Final data(.arff)]

*Shouldn't this be 26 for all letters in the latin alphabet?

Comment: Thank you , i have the CSV file seperated by commas and my problem is converting it to arff file , how can i define 1024 attributes? Should i use a for loop ? And what codes should i write in order to make a arff file out of my CSV to have 1024 attributes? Where should i write the codes and run it to create the arff file? Thank you so much

Comment: If you have a CSV file such as one in the image, the easiest way that I know of is to simply open the CSV file in the WEKA GUI client, and save it as an ARFF file. 

You can open a CSV file by selecting the CSV filetype in [the explorer that comes up](https://i.imgur.com/NOkIjv1.png), and then save it as an ARFF file by pressing the save button and chosing to [save it as an ARFF file](https://i.imgur.com/GmgOOaq.png).